# Left coset is generated by the element of G, but not H

Tags: abstract-algebra, normal-subgroups

left coset of ***H*** in ***G*** is a subset of ***G*** of type ***aH*** for some element ***a*** of ***G***. Why does nobody requires element ***a*** not to belong to ***H*** itself?

Comment: Because $H$ is a perfectly good coset.

Comment: Note:  $aH=H$ when $a\in H$

Comment: $eH=H$ is the coset belonging to the neutral element $e$. We need not miss it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not? If $a\in H$, then $aH=H$, which is indeed a coset.

Answer (score 0):

The (left) cosets of $H$ are the sets $aH = \{ ah : h \in H \}$, and two cosets are equal if they are equal as sets, so maybe $aH = bH$ even if $a \neq b$.

With this in mind you can see that $\forall g \in H$, $gH = \{ gh : h \in H \} = H$. So every element of $H$ makes the same left coset of $H$, which is just $H$ itself.

For different elements outside of $H$, we will get other cosets that are different from $H$ itself, although usually there will be multiple elements that will give you the same coset of $H$. In fact, the only time that every element of $G$ will give a different left coset of $H$ will be if $H$ is the trivial subgroup.

And the direct answer to your question is that, as mentioned, $H$ itself is a perfectly valid coset. In fact, when $H$ is normal, within the quotient group $G/H$, the coset $H$ is the identity element, and within the original group, the subgroup $H \trianglelefteq G$ is the kernel of the [canonical homomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorems#First_isomorphism_theorem) $\varphi: G \to G/H$

Comment: you have an extra }

Comment: fixed it thanks